# Double if statement in java (swing, JFrame) not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make a form so that when a user checks a checkbox and clicks a button, some code will execute. I've tried to do this in an `if` statement and nothing happens when I do the 2 things. I am doing this in Java with Swing.

Here is the code:

```
private class theHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        String tftext;
        tftext = tf1.getText();

        if (event.getSource()==b1)
            if(event.getSource()==cb1)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, tftext, "title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

`b1` is a button, `cb1` is a checkbox and `tf1` is a textfield.

Comment: event.getSource() cannot be both b1 and cb1...keyboard mistake  cb1 => b1?

Comment: `Here is the code` :-) for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: CORRECT: event.getSource() cannot be both b1 and cb1.  [You must pick one or the other](http://www.sing365.com/music/lyric.nsf/Just-Like-Tom-Thumb%27s-Blues-lyrics-Bob-Dylan/BDB41AD9585D4C704825696900293B3F) ;)

Answer (score 5):

`Event.getSource()` won't reference *two different* objects, it should reference the unique source of a single event, e.g. a Button in the case of a button click. Your nested statement will never execute.

It sounds like you should be handling the button click, and within that event handler check the state (checked or not) of the checkbox. If the checkbox is checked, then show your dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Basically what you are saying there is that if the event came from the button and the event came from the checkbox, show a message.

This is not possible because one event cannot be triggered by a button and a checkbox in the same time. You cannot click on both in the same time.